# Bold First Line of Output

Tags: php

I need to add `<b>` tags around the first line of text, but not contained in a paragraph tag - rather just all the text before the first `<br>`.

It's a PHP string being echoed, so it seems to me pretty simple but I'm not sure how I'd get just that section of text, bold it, and then continue with the rest as normal.

```
$str = "First Line<br>SecondLine<br>Third Line<br>";
echo $str;

//output:
<b>First Line</b><br>SecondLine<br>ThirdLine<br>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substr` and `strpos` to the rescue!

```
$firstBreak = strpos($str, '<br>');

if($firstBreak === false) {
    $str = "<b>$str</b>";
} else {
    $str = '<b>' . substr($str, 0, $firstBreak) . '</b>' . substr($str, $firstBreak);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$first_line = explode('<br>', $str)[0];
$new_str = str_replace($first_line,'<b>'.$first_line.'</b>',$str);
```